# interactive ui in html mail client

Tags: html, dom

I want to have this scenario. Two radio buttons. And on selection of 1 a  should be visible and on selection of other radio button another div should appear.

```
<html>
    <h2>Displaying interactive information</h2>
    <div><br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1">
        <input type="radio" name="group2">
    <div>

    <div id="two">
    <div>
    <div id="one">
    </div>
</html>
```

If group1 is selected id one should be visible and when group2 is selected div id two should be visible.

If I use javascript to do the same, it won't work. as looks like script is not executing in mail.

Is there any direct way of achieving it without javascript/ jquery as they won't execute in web mail client.

Comment: If you put the `input`s at the same level as the `div`s you could probably use the `:checked` and sibling (`~`) selector to achieve this. However, as you are attempting this in an email it is unlikely to work consistently as email clients offer varying amount of CSS support https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

Comment: if this works in gmail should be ok. Can you help with the code.

Comment: It is unlikely to work in Gmail as if https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ can be believed it does support the sibling selector.